# Change 2 ASCII numbers into ints in C

Tags: c

I'm working on a project where I need to take in a line from a file (ie read `stdin` until a `\n` character) that contains two arbitrary numbers in ASCII format separated by a whitespace character and output the two numbers as integers.
I also need to use this process later on an arbitrary number of ASCII number inputs, so my solution also has to scale.

I tried using `getc(stdin)` to traverse the file, but since these numbers are (often) multi-digit I've been hinted to use `scanf` to help. However, the documentation for `scanf` is completely inscrutable to me and I don't see why it would be useful for this problem. I tried

```
int i1 = scanf(stdin, &i1);
//need to skip the whitespace character here
char c = getc(stdin);
int i2 = scanf(stdin, &i2);
printf("&d %d\n", i1, i2);
```

but this sets `i1` and `i2` to 0. I'm sort of at a loss so anything here would probably help.

Comment: What do you mean with `"arbitrary number of ASCII number inputs"`? Do you mean an arbitrary number of ASCII number inputs **in the same line**? Or do you rather mean an arbitrary number of lines, each containing two numbers?

Comment: scanf takes different args than you have , your compiler is surely screaming at you

Comment: `int i1, i2; scanf("%d %d", &i1, &i2);`?

Comment: `printf("&d` -> `printf("%d`

Comment: Use `fscanf()` - `fscanf (stdin, "%d %d", &i1, &i2);`.

Answer (score 0):

- ***Logic*** :
  *(you can use this logic for only the ASCII value of the number)*,
- take the ASCII number and subtract it by 48. Since the ASCII value of 1 is 49, 49-48 gives 1. similarly the ASCII value of 2 is 50, 50-48 = 2.And so on.
- ***Solution*** :

  ```
   int n;
   while (fscanf(inputFile, " %d", &n) == 1) {
   printf("%d\n", n-48);
   }
  ```